# C# WPF show multible tables on one listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listbox

I have an idea to bind multible tables from database to one `listbox`, but I don't know how to do it. I have 3 sources named Boozes, Juices and Snacks. Right now i have only Boozes table shown on the listbox.

My `MainWindow.Xaml` code :

```
 <ListBox Name="BoozeList" ItemsSource="{Binding Boozes}"
             Margin="10,124,0,10"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              Width="233" Background="#FF79DCFA" BorderBrush="#FF0040FF">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UnitPrice}" />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Combine 3 tables to one (either Beverage datatable or IEnumerable<Beverage>), bind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your itemssource to a composite collection:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="BoozesCollection" Source="{Binding Boozes}"/>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="JuicesCollection" Source="{Binding Juices}"/>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SnacksCollection" Source="{Binding Snacks}"/>

<CompositeCollection>
    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource BoozesCollection}}"/>
    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource JuicesCollection}}"/>
    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource SnacksCollection}}"/>
</CompositeCollection>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a little bit better explanation how to implement it. I could not get it working in any way.

Comment: you define the 3 collectionviewsources in your <ListBox.Resources> and then you put the composite collection code in <ListBox.ItemsSource> *composite collection snippet here* </ListBox.ItemsSource>. makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Just merge all the three into one table and bind it.

```
dtAll.Merge(dtOne);
dtAll.Merge(dtTwo);
dtAll.Merge(dtThree);
```